# VSCode does not debug when using LLDB on Windows 10

Tags: c++, json, windows, lldb

I installed the LLDB extension in VSCode, but when I am trying to debug it just does not happen. Instead the program just executes.

My tasks.json:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:/MinGW64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "-Wall",
            "-std=c++17",
            "${fileDirname}\\*.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:/MinGW64/mingw64/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: C:/MinGW64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"
    }
]
```

}

My launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
    }
]
```

}

Does anybody know what the problem is ?

Comment: If you compile with g++, you should debug with gdb. If you really want to debug with LLDB, you should compile with clang++, and use the LLDB extension to create your launch.json for you. That also doesn't look like a generated launch.json, they typically have a field for the build task to execute.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you didn't set any breakpoints or watchpoints, then the program will just execute until it finishes or crashes.